# OpenGL Missing Triangles Diffuse Shader

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, blender

I'm using C++ and when I implemented a diffuse shader, it causes every other triangle to disappear. [image: Cube OBJ]

[image: Torus OBJ]

I can post my render code if need be, but I believe the issue is with my normal matrix (which I wrote it to be the transpose inverse of the model view matrix). Here is the shader code which is sort of similar to that of a tutorial on lighthouse tutorials.
VERTEX SHADER

```
#version 330

layout(location=0) in vec3 position;
layout(location=1) in vec3 normal;

uniform mat4 transform_matrix;
uniform mat4 view_model_matrix;
uniform mat4 normal_matrix;
uniform vec3 light_pos;

out vec3 light_intensity;

void main()
{
    vec3 tnorm = normalize(normal_matrix * vec4(normal, 1.0)).xyz;
    vec4 eye_coords = transform_matrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    vec3 s = normalize(vec3(light_pos - eye_coords.xyz)).xyz;

    vec3 light_set_intensity = vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    vec3 diffuse_color = vec3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);

    light_intensity = light_set_intensity * diffuse_color * max(dot(s, tnorm), 0.0);
    gl_Position = transform_matrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

My fragment shader just outputs the "light_intensity" in the form of a color. My model is straight from Blender and I have tried different exporting options like keeping vertex order, but nothing has worked.

Comment: try changing the order of your vertices in one of your triangle. It seems like it's a winding problem

Comment: are you referring to changing the model?

Comment: Yes, your faces seems not to follow the same winding, try playing a bit with order of your vertices

Comment: I don't think the problem is with your normal matrix. If that were wrong, all your triangles would get wrong lighting, and half of them are correct. I suspect that the problem is with the normals pointing in the wrong direction. This is similar to the winding problem @HarrisonG16 suggested. But if the winding is wrong, and you have back face culling enabled, the triangles would not be draw at all. They show up in black here, so they are not eliminated. Is there any way your modeling software can show the normals? They should all be pointing outwards.

Comment: To build on what @RetoKoradi said, I've written a shader to output the x, y, and z of the normal in the r, g, and b channels. I've found that a good way to double-check normals.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: why are you assuming backface culling is on, sure it's not :-)

Comment: @RetoKoradi: square faces are made of 2 triangles, you may have your drawing routine miss behave with only one of them, that's classical error.

Comment: Show your fragment shader too, it appears that some calculations are in there. (your faces would appear with only 1 single solid color if it was not the case)

Comment: There aren't any calculations in my fragment shader. It's only one line in the main that is

FragColor = vec4(light_intensity, 1.0);

The light-intensity caries the new color (that has intensity and diffuse color with it). I tried changing vertex order in blender, but I got the same result, but the missing are there and the ones that are there, are missing.

How can you do the correct order in a blender export?

Comment: Also, I'm using SDL, GLEW, and GLM if that matters (same result on linux and windows).

Comment: @HarrisonG16: if the model is from blender export, it has surely the right indices. How is it loaded into your app? self made loader for obj? or something else?

Comment: @j-p: On the backface culling: You had suggested that the problem was with the winding of the faces. The winding only really matters if you have backface culling enabled. At least I can't think on any other OpenGL features that depend on the winding order of the triangles.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: because the shader use face orientation, the order(that's what I'm talking about when I say winding) the indices are declared will affect face color, but they are not discarded (culling would completely discard them) but all faces are presented, not well lightened, but not discarded

Comment: @HarrisonG16: what do you mean `straight from blender`? it's a c++ exporter?

Comment: No I meant like what option should I choose in Blender in order to order the vertices a certain way.

@RetoKoradi, I have not changed anything having to do with backface culling so are you saying I should disable it?

Comment: I noticed just now that when I change the "keep normals consistent inside", the mesh either becomes all black on the outside or all gray on the outside.

Comment: @Harrison: when modeling with blender, it's good to recompute normals, and remove duplicate vertices (left edit pannel)

Comment: I just used the normals as the color and noticed that some of them were black and others were red, blue, and green. However, I can't tell whether or not it is actually a depth issue because I can't see depth when I render without colors (so I can't see overwritten/overlayed triangles). If depth test doesn't work, what else could I use?

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to you shader.

It appears to be depth test related. Here, the order of triangles in the depth relative to you viewport is messed up, because you do not make sure that only the nearest pixel to your camera gets drawn.

Enable depth testing and make sure you have a z buffer bound to your render target.
Read more about this here: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Depth_Test

[image: Triangles of the cube with wrong depth test.]

Only the triangles highlighted in red should be visible to the viewer. Due to the lack of a valid depth test, there is no chance to guarantee, what triangle is painted top most. Thus blue triangles of the faces that should not be visible will cover parts of previously drawn red triangles.

The depth test would omit this, by comparing the depth in the z buffer with the depth of the pixel to be drawn at the current moment. Only the color information of a pixel that is closer to the viewer, i.e. has a smaller z value than the z value in the buffer, shall be written to the framebuffer in order to achieve a correct result.

(Backface culling, would be nice too and, if the model is correctly exported, also allow to show it correctly. But it would only hide the main problem, not solve it.)

Comment: not sure, some depth testing seems to work well (look at the top face)

Comment: The top face might be luck. It just happens to be the last face drawn. (Of the faces which could cover the top face)

Comment: only the front left face could lead to think to depth testing problem, I'm not quite convinced

Comment: Why only the left face? Each primitive appears to be from the cube, the order of how they are drawn is just counter intuitive. But still makes sense, e.g. the bottom right triangle is drawn rather late (if not as last triangle).  Play around with the indices (move always whole triangles together, assuming you have a per face indexing) and you'll get different results.

Comment: because front left side has a strange _ghost_ vertex appearing in the middle of the top front left segment. I think it's possibly caused by: the closest vertex from the camera may not be linked at all (wrong indice), but the farthest one is substituted(not sure its clear).

Comment: Interesting idea, but I don't think it's the depth test. For example, there's one polygon in the cube image (I wish I could point at it, it's close to the center) that is back facing, but is lighted like it's front facing. That's why I still believe that some normals are pointing in the wrong direction.

Comment: Enabling depth test causes everything to disappear. Not sure if that helps. Do you need any sort of depth testing if you're using ONLY shaders to render?

Comment: You don't need id. But if you want it to look right, you need it. Can you please post how you set it up? Also make sure to clear also the depth buffer when calling glClear. There is no difference between using the depth test with shaders or the fixed function pipeline in this context.

Comment: I don't know why this answer has been down-voted. It is almost certainly correct. You can clearly see a triangle which has been over-drawn by another which should be behind it. As user3407721 says, make sure you are calling `glClear` with `GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT` and you are requesting a depth buffer when setting up the device context.

Comment: Thanks for seeing my point. I added a picture and more detailed explanations in order to clarify how this faulty image is generated.

Comment: Yes - that image explains it very well. Would up-vote again if I could. Your point about back-face culling is correct too.